# Conditional Query in Access to Select Max Date

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working with a dataset that looks like this:

```
 ZeroCurveID  MarkRunID  MarkAsOfDate
    90-6589      6656       2/28/2012
    90-6589      6656       2/28/2012
    90-6589      6656       2/28/2012
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/6/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/6/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
    14-8898      8898       8/12/2014
```

For a given ZeroCurveID and MarkRunID, there should only be one MarkAsofDate. So for ZeroCurveID = 14-8898 and MarkRunID = 8898, MarkAsofDate must equal 8/12/2014 and any other values are not correct.

In some cases, I have two MarkAsofDate values for the same MarkRunID and ZeroCurveID. I want to create a query to identify when these instances occur, and to select the larger of the MarkAsofDate value as the correct value. How can I design a Query or VBA subroutine to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL statement returns all combinations of ZeroCurveID and MarkRunID for which **multiple** MarkAsOfDates exist, along with the maximum MarkAsOfDate:

```
SELECT ZeroCurveID, MarkRunID, MAX(MarkAsOfDate)
FROM t
GROUP BY ZeroCurveID, MarkRunID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And this selects all combinations that actually have **different** MarkAsOfDates, but it does not tell the maximum date:

```
SELECT ZeroCurveID, MarkRunID, COUNT(DISTINCT MarkAsOfDate) AS nDups
FROM t
GROUP BY ZeroCurveID, MarkRunID
HAVING nDups > 1
```

Performance-wise, it may be better to first use one of the above SQLs to get a list of entries that actually need to be corrected, and then update them individually (using parameters `@zcid` and `@mrid`):

```
UPDATE t
SET MarkAsOfDate = ( SELECT MAX(t2.MarkAsOfDate)
    FROM t AS t2
    WHERE t2.ZeroCurveID = t.ZeroCurveID AND
          t2.MarkRunID = t.MarkRunID )
WHERE ZeroCurveID = @zcid AND MarkRunID = @mrid
```

Otherwise, you could do it all in one go with this big SQL statement:

```
UPDATE t
SET MarkAsOfDate = ( SELECT MAX(t2.MarkAsOfDate)
    FROM t AS t2
    WHERE t2.ZeroCurveID = t.ZeroCurveID AND
          t2.MarkRunID = t.MarkRunID )
WHERE 1 < ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t3.MarkAsOfDate)
    FROM t AS t3
    WHERE t3.ZeroCurveID = t.ZeroCurveID AND
          t3.MarkRunID = t.MarkRunID )
```